# whats is the manipulation about $(|z+h|^2-|z|^2)/h$ as $h \Rightarrow 0$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

i need to prove that this limit is the circunference $C(\overset{-}{z},|z|))$ but i'm twining in the end of this calculus

$\displaystyle\underset{z \Rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{(z+h)(\overset{-}{z}+\overset{-}{h}) - |z|}{h} = \underset{z \Rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{\overset{-}{z}h + z\overset{-}{h}+\overset{-}{z}\overset{-}{h}}{h}$

how can i put $h$ in evidence in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{|z+h|^2-|z|^2}{h}&=\frac{z\bar h+\bar zh+|h|^2}{h}\\\\
&=\frac{2\text{Re}(\bar zh)+|h|^2}{h}\\\\
&=\frac{2|z||h|\cos(\theta-\phi)+|h|^2}{h} 
\end{align}$$

where $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ and $h=|h|e^{i\phi}$.

The limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|}{h}$ does not exist since the left-side limit and right-side limit are not equal.

Therefore the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|z+h|^2-|z|^2}{h}$ fails to exist except when $z=0$ where the limit is $0$.

Comment: sorry, could you look again the questios? i just forgot to say that $f(z) = |z|^2$ and i'm traying to look for the acumulation points of that quotient as $h$ goes to zero

Comment: So what about the acumulation points of $g(z) = (f(z+h)-f(z))/h$ as $h$ goes to zero? the exercise was misconceived?

Comment: For $z=0$, $0$ is a limit point.  For $z\ne 0$ there is no limit point.